# "Code is unreachable" but code still gets reached (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code that accesses a website and stops browser notifications:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
***option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
option.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2 
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=option)
driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/")
```

The code runs, but my IDE (Visual Studio Code) says that from *** onwards the "Code is unreachable Pylance". Does anyone know how I could fix this? It's annoying since it grays out everything after the *** line. Thank you.

Visual representation of what I'm seeing:

[image]

With warning:

[image]

Comment: The definition of the `.add_experimental_option()` method appears to have a type hint along the lines of `-> NoReturn`, indicating that execution doesn't continue normally once you call it.  I have no idea why it would be written like that; maybe this will at least give you a search term to help find where the erroneous type hint is located.

Comment: @jasonharper Omg thank you so much. I didn't notice that and it helped me find the solution. Turns out – it's a bug. Updating to the most recent version of selenium fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

It's a bug. Update to the most recent version of selenium to fix the issue.

I found this out by finding the same issue also being discussed here: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2807

Comment: And remember to do Python: Restart Language Server

Comment: I am not using the seleneium package, and im still getting this issue. Im using `StringIO`, `re`, `datetime`, `pandas`, and `urllib.parse`